# NullPointerException for getDataSource().getConnection()

Tags: jsp, tomcat, datasource, connection-pooling

I have a jsp+servlets web application deployed in tomcat server. I'm using connection pooling as shown below

```
public class DBConnection {

    public static DataSource datasource = null;

    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        return datasource;
    }

    static {
        initializeDataSource();
    }

    public static void initializeDataSource() {
        try {
            InitialContext initialContext;
            initialContext = new InitialContext();
            Context context = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            datasource = (DataSource) context.lookup("dbconn");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

To get the connection:

```
Connection connection = DBConnection.getDataSource().getConnection();
```

context.xml

```
<Context path="/adminapp">
  <Resource auth="Container" defaultAutoCommit="false" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" logAbandoned="true" maxIdle="5" maxTotal="150" maxWaitMillis="-1" minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="60000" name="dbconn" password="" removeAbandonedOnBorrow="true" removeAbandonedOnMaintenance="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="300" timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="180000" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/data?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" username="root"/>
</Context>
```

I deployed this app in tomcat works fine. I'm able to access the app using url https://example.com:8443/adminapp/

Now i switched to virual host in tomcat by changing tomcat server xml as below

```
    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
  </Host>

  <Host name="adminapp.example.com"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false">



    <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
    <!--
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
    -->

    <!-- Access log processes all example.
         Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
         Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
    <Context path="" docBase="knestlms_admin"/>
  </Host>
```

After having virtual host i'm getting this error in log:

```
 javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:839)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at Utils.DBConnection.initializeDataSource(DBConnection.java:36)
    at Utils.DBConnection.<clinit>(DBConnection.java:28)
    at org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:221)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:457)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:395)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:316)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRewrittenUrl.doRewrite(NormalRewrittenUrl.java:213)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:171)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on [tomcat and JNDI](https://memorynotfound.com/configure-jndi-datasource-tomcat/).

Comment: @Luis Muñoz It is working fine without Virtual host. But when i configured virtual host to tomcat it is not working.

Comment: @Luis Muñoz This worked. But why i need to define <GlobalNamingResources> and <ResourceLink>. Why can't i keep all inside my app WEB-INF/context.xml as i did for without virtual host config

Comment: Check that your context.xml [inside the virtual host directories](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/virtual-hosting-howto.html) is correct and contains the Resource.